# Unity3d - How to walk throught streets

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a 3d city model. I want to walk throught walls/steets. There are some advices for this.

[Ex1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/796018/character-walking-through-walls.html), [ex2](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/125850/1st-person-controller-walks-through-wallsbuildings.html), [ex3](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/walking-through-walls.86418/)

Generally, they said that you should add a collider to your model. I did it. But I don't know next step. Should I move my camera or player gameobject? Should I handle click movement key in code?

Answer (score 0):

I attach below code to my camera. It works for me. I take this code from [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-XwAF5iCKE)

```
public float speed = 10.0f;
public float rotationSpeed = 100.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float translation = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * speed;
    float rotation = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
    translation *= Time.deltaTime;
    rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate (0, 0, translation);
    transform.Rotate (0, rotation, 0);
}
```